# Wrong results in osrm self hosted API

Tags: optimization, routes, osrm, vroom

Happy new year 2022! This is my first question

I've implemented a setup of OSRM + Vroom in GCP (Google Cloud Platform) following the instructions described in this tutorial: https://medium.com/@calroughan/a-beginners-guide-to-installing-osrm-and-vroom-on-gcp-28fbcf1f7857. But in my case, I'm using Colombia's geographic data.

All installation proccess went well, and I got both services up and running. The problem: I'm getting wrong results in Vroom API responses.

For example, I send this simple petition to OSRM service:
ttp://35.209.254.69:5000/route/v1/driving/4.647868,-74.1134533;4.755680799999999,-74.0236338?overview=simplified&steps=true&geometries=polyline.
And I'm getting this result:

```
{"code":"Ok","routes":[{"geometry":"|awXbnkiL??","legs":[{"steps":[{"intersections":[{"out":0,"entry":[true],"bearings":[106],"location":[-69.859695,-4.219346]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"|awXbnkiL??","mode":"driving","duration":0,"maneuver":{"bearing_after":106,"location":[-69.859695,-4.219346],"bearing_before":0,"type":"depart"},"weight":0,"distance":0,"name":"Rua Perimetral Norte Um"},{"intersections":[{"in":0,"entry":[true],"bearings":[286],"location":[-69.859695,-4.219346]}],"driving_side":"right","geometry":"|awXbnkiL","mode":"driving","duration":0,"maneuver":{"bearing_after":0,"location":[-69.859695,-4.219346],"bearing_before":106,"type":"arrive"},"weight":0,"distance":0,"name":"Rua Perimetral Norte Um"}],"distance":0,"duration":0,"summary":"Rua Perimetral Norte Um","weight":0}],"distance":0,"duration":0,"weight_name":"routability","weight":0}],"waypoints":[{"hint":"4dsOgOrwDoAAAAAAXgAAAAAAAACfLAAAAAAAAHiagkIAAAAArrf3RQAAAABeAAAAAAAAAJ8sAACtAQAAkQbW-y6ev_-860YAUx6V-wAA7xEdQq-f","distance":10082832.728969,"name":"Rua Perimetral Norte Um","location":[-69.859695,-4.219346]},{"hint":"4dsOgOrwDoAAAAAAXgAAAAAAAACfLAAAAAAAAHiagkIAAAAArrf3RQAAAABeAAAAAAAAAJ8sAACtAQAAkQbW-y6ev__hkEgALn2W-wAA7xEdQq-f","distance":10083985.308367,"name":"Rua Perimetral Norte Um","location":[-69.859695,-4.219346]}]}
```

The result below is wrong because the distance and duration properties in the route[0] are 0. If I do the same example in the osrm frontend demo I got the following result:
https://map.project-osrm.org/?z=13&center=4.699297%2C-74.067215&loc=4.646360%2C-74.111818&loc=4.754348%2C-74.022195&hl=en&alt=0&srv=1.
You can watch it in this image
[OSRM frontend same example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRvOI.jpg)

In a more complex routing optimization case I'm observing very weird geometries like the next one:
[Initial deliveries located in Barranquilla, Colombia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MClip.png)

And after applying route optimization with vroom, this is the resulting geometry for one of the routes

[Resulted weird geometry for one of the routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X8vZ.png)

As you can see, this Polyline has no sense at all, because its size is stupidly bigger than the initial deliveries geometry

So, my question is: Has anyone faced a similar problem with OSRM or Vroom self-hosted solutions? What could I be doing wrong?

I appreciate any suggestion and/or recommendation which takes me in the right direction to solve this issue.